# ReactNative - Struggling with first example I am trying to follow and learn from

Tags: react-native

I am following this article by Denislav Ganchev to write my very first React Native app.  I started learning about ReactNative just a couple of days ago. https://mentormate.com/blog/react-native-components/

However, I am stuck on the step "Developing Our App" in this article.  It shows the structure like this and I don't see it created in my project at all:

[image]

As I am a complete beginner with ReactNative, I am unable to continue and modify these files.

Do I need to manually create the structure and if so, in which folder in the folder structure?  I wish the screenshot would show more of the structure to see where it should go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article has a download link: github.com/denodenodeno/employee. The project has the structure.